# How to move subscripts to the right and text to the left

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have

```
\[
\sum_{\substack{m \in [1,\dots,n] \\ b \in \{0,1\}}}
P[y_{i_\ell}= z_{i_\ell}\mid xxx]
\]
```

For space reasons I need to move the subscripts so that they are flush left with the summation sign and then move $P$ to the left so that it directly follows the summation sign and so is above the subscripts.    How can you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate way to accomplish the stacking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrel{%
  \stackunder{$\displaystyle\sum$}{%
    \stackunder{$\scriptstyle m \in [1,\dots,n]$}%
               {$\scriptstyle b \in \{0,1\}$}%
  }%
}
P[y_{i_\ell}= z_{i_\ell}\mid xxx]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you felt there was too much confusion in the subscripts of the sum, you could make them `\scriptscriptstyle` instead of `\scriptstyle`, to get

[image]

In answer to the query of whether this can be placed into a macro, I do it below with the double subscript in `\scriptscriptstyle`, using a newly created macro I call `\doublesubsum{}{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\doublesubsum[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \stackunder{$\displaystyle\sum$}{%
      \stackunder{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}%
                 {$\scriptscriptstyle #2$}%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\doublesubsum{m \in [1,\dots,n]}{b \in \{0,1\}}%
P[y_{i_\ell}= z_{i_\ell}\mid xxx]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. As I need to do this a lot, is it possible to define a macro to avoid having the main LaTeX full of stackunders?

Comment: @penfold Yes.  I have revised to demonstrate.

Comment: It seems stackengine is not in texlive 2012. Is that right?

Comment: @penfold  I don't use TeXlive, so I can't answer that.  But it is a new package, so (if not) it may make it to their next edition.  In fact, I'm going to upload a new version today that will allow you to indicate that arguments should be treated, by default, in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

You simply do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}
m \in [1,\dots,n] \\ 
b \in \{0,1\}
\end{subarray}}P[y_{i_\ell}= z_{i_\ell}\mid xxx]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To left align with the summation, you can use `\phantom{mmm}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}
\phantom{mmm}m \in [1,\dots,n] \\ 
\phantom{mmm}b \in \{0,1\}
\end{subarray}}\hspace{-.5cm}P[y_{i_\ell}= z_{i_\ell}\mid xxx]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: pic2]

Comment: I was hoping to have the subscripts flush left with the summation sign and for $P[y_{i_\ell}= z_{i_\ell}\mid xxx]$ to follow directly after the summation sign (and not after the right end of the subscripts).

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I now need to move the probability to the left. Should I just add lots of \! 's?

Comment: @penfold I just added `\hspace{-.5cm}` in front of the probability.  You can go more or less by adjusting `-.5`.

Comment: @penfold no problem.